# How to make a Web App for a Windows 8 and Android Tablet for D3js application

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, windows-8, d3.js

I have a javascript / html / css web "application" that makes use of the D3 visualization library to visualize a file system with Bootstrap, which works well on a desktop / laptop.

I now need to move this application a tablet and need to support both Windows 8 and Android. But I am really confused on the best way to do this.

D3 is javascript based, so I cannot make a native app for each supported operating system. Should I convert the code to mobile web apps via each SDK or use another approach, such as Phonegap (or alternatives) to do this?

If I use the SDKs then I would need to handle separate versions of the code to update any changes, but I am not sure if Phonegap is what I am looking for as it seems difficult to get started with it. I only need to support Windows 8 and Android - is there any easier way?

Lastly, if I create an app using Phonegap, can I access a database located in a cloud or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need Phonegap for this. You can build native apps that only hold a WebView that fills the entire screen. The WebView will host your "web application".
Then, (and here's the funny part) you write interfaces in order to access native objects.

In Android you write a javascript interface as a class with public methods annotated with `@JavascriptInterface`.

```
class MyJsInterface{
  @JavascriptInterface
  public String doStuff() { return "hello" ; }
}
```

You register your javascript interface on your webview using `addJavascriptInterface` method:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJsInterface(), "MyInterface");
```

From javascript you can access the methods of your interface using the name provided as the second parameter of the method above (`MyInterface` in this case):

```
var message = window.MyInterface.doStuff();
// message is 'hello'
```

Methods that return string (JSON) work nicely with javascript. 
Read more about [Android WebView and javascript interfaces](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29).

With Windows you can achieve similar functionality using:

- the InvokeScript method of the WebView (or browser control) which allows you to pass data from C# to javascript
- the Notify method (`window.external.notify`) which allows you to send data from javascript to C# and raise the `ScriptNotify` event on the control.

Nice article: [Windows Phone 8 native and Javascript interop](http://www.jayway.com/2014/03/10/windows-phone-8-native-and-javascript-interop/)
MSDN Link: [WebBrowser.ScriptNotify Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.scriptnotify%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Don't forget to enable javascript on your webviews.